# Stream S3 file from a one AWS subaccount, Flink deployed on Kubernetes cluster in another AWS account

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, apache-flink, amazon-iam, flink-streaming

1. I have 2 AWS accounts, `Account A` and `Account B`.
2. `Account A` has a EKS cluster running with a flink cluster running on it. To manage the IAM roles, we use `Kube2iam`.
3. All the pods on cluster have specific roles assigned to them. For simplicity lets say the role for one of the pods is `Pod-Role`
4. The K8s worker nodes have the role `Worker-Node-role`
5. Kube2iam is correctly configured to make proper EC2 metadata calls when required.
6. `Account B` has a S3 bucket, which the `Pod` hosted in `Account A` worked node need to read.

Possible Solution:

1. Create a role in `Account B`, let's say, `AccountB_Bucket_access_role` with a policy that allows reading the bucket. Add `Pod-Role` as a trusted entity to it.
2. Add a policy in `Pod-role` which allows switching to `AccountB_Bucket_access_role`, basically the `STS AssumeRole` action.
3. Create a AWS profile in Pod, let's say, `custom_profile`, with `role_arn` set to `AccountB_Bucket_access_role` role's arn.
4. While deploying the flink pod, set `AWS_PROFILE=AccountB_Bucket_access_role`.

**QUESTION:** Given above whenever the flink app needs to talk to S3 bucket, it first assumes the `AccountB_Bucket_access_role` role and is able to read the S3 bucket. But setting `AWS_PROFILE` actually switches the role for flink app, hence all the `POD-ROLE` permissions are lost, and they are required for proper functioning of flink app.

Is there a way, that this AWS `custom_profile` could only be used when reading S3 bucket and it switches to `POD-ROLE` after that.

```
val flinkEnv: StreamExecutionEnvironment = AppUtils.setUpAndGetFlinkEnvRef(config.flink)
val textInputFormat = new TextInputFormat(new Path(config.path))
env
 .readFile(
    textInputFormat,
    config.path,
    FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY,
    config.refreshDurationMs
 )
```

This is what I use in flink job to read S3 file.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, we can configure a role of one account to access a particular bucket from another account. [Access Bucket from another account](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/)